# Clone and Cocoon, what happens.?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I'm currently creating a high level caster (3.5) for fun and I came across an odd spell combination.

Clone (source: PHB, Arcane spell) basically this spell makes a clone of your body (that you have to grow in a lab, and maintain until you... for lack of a better word, use it).  when you die your soul immediately goes to that body and you awake with no level loss.  Your original body is rendered useless for purposes of resurrection

Cocoon (Source: Spell Compendium, Druid spell) This spell when cast on a freshly dead body wraps the body in a cocoon and preserves the body until it can be later resurrected.  If the body is not resurrected with in a week, the body inside is resurrected via the reincarnate spell.

The key parts here are that Clone does not resurrect you (I've checked the text multiple times and it says nothing about resurrection, just that the soul returns to the body).  And Cocoon specifically preserves the body.

I think I have an idea of what would happens but just wanted to see what others thought.
If I cast my clone spell and make my clone then set a spell triggered Cocoon spell on myself.  when I die would my character awake in the clone body and then a week later would my previous body be reincarnated?

I think I would just awake as my clone and the original body would be useless but just wanted other opinions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text for the Clone spell says:

> If the original individual has been slain, its soul immediately transfers to the clone, creating a replacement (provided that the soul is free and willing to return; see Bringing Back the Dead, page 171). The original's physical remains, should they still exist, **become inert and cannot thereafter be restored to life**.

This states that even a Cocoon spell would not be able to reincarnate the original remains, because it can't restore the creature to life.

The original body, while preserved, no longer has a soul (as the soul has moved into the clone body.) Effectively, the original body and clone trade states, with the clone becoming an active, living being and the remains becoming soulless, lifeless, and inert. However, while the original remains are in the cocoon, they will not rot or decay.

Comment: So Cocoon's effect of preserving the body would not counter that effect of the clone spell then.

Comment: The body is preserved, but inert, as if it never was alive in the first place. I'll expand on my answer

Comment: I wonder if this could be used to create a second clone.  RAW it doesn't look like you could use the cocooned body as a clone, but I bet there are DMs that would allow this.

Comment: @ZellFaze I would. Of course, I'd also introduce a mysterious NPC who offers to buy the soulless body "To become home to a poor soul who lost their own..."

Comment: @ZellFaze Since the body is flesh and larger than 1 cubic inch, you could use it to create a new clone. If there's any reduction to the growth time would be subject to DM discretion.